# Controlling access to folders for a single user

Tags: linux, centos

I have many folders under the directory `/home/storage` I want a user `guest` to be able to access only `/home/storage/guest` and no other folders under `/home/storage` The rest of the users should be able to access all other folders How do I set these permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is:

Set all directories in `/home/storage` with group ID matching `staff` (or whatever name you prefer).

Normal users are members of `staff` (maybe use this by default instead of a group matching the user name), while `guest` is not. He gets the permissions from being the owner of `/home/storage/guest`, but cannot see the other `staff` directories.

And of course make sure `other`-permissions are denied.

Answer (score 0):

if you very much particular about providing access to guest user for folder /home/storage/guest using acl

```
format: setfacl -m u:guest:rwx /home/storage/guest
```